# The number of threads and blocks needed for adding two vectors of length 2^20

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

- [Vector Addition in CUDA](https://youtu.be/uUEHuF5i_qI?list=PLxNPSjHT5qvvwoy6KXzUbLaF5A8NdJvuo&t=723)

> We want to add two vectors of length 2^20. What would the threads-per_block and blocks_per_grid declarations look like?

This was discussed in the above video.

He declared it like the following:

```
int THREADS = 256;
int BLOCKS = (2^20 + THREADS - 1)/THREADS;
```

That means he is using single dimensions in both.

**My solution is as follows:**

We need 2^20 = 10,48,576 threads.

My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce 780. This GPU has a computing capability of 3.5. For compute capability 3.5, the maximum number of threads per block is 1024, and the maximum number of blocks per grid is 2^31-1, or approximately 2.1 billion.

However, the actual maximum number of threads per block and blocks per grid that can be used in a CUDA program is limited by the available resources on the GPU, such as the amount of shared memory and registers per block, and the total number of threads that can be resident on the GPU at the same time.

Let us say, we will use three dimensions and a much lower value of 512 threads per grid. 512 can be factored into 8x8x8. So, the declaration for threads per block would be:

```
dim3 threads_per_block(8, 8, 8); //512
```

If each block has 512 threads, then, we need 10,48,576 / 512 = 2048 blocks.

The cube root of 2048 is 12.6992084157. So, we will take 16x16x16 blocks. So the declaration will look like as follows:

```
dim3 blocks_per_grid(16,16,16); //4096
```

**Is this calculation correct?**

Comment: "We need 2^20 = 10,48,576 threads" - claim not supported by evidence prior to claim, nor after, it is just asserted without evidence.  Clearly you can solve this problem with fewer than 1 million threads, so "need" is the wrong word.  Did you mean "we WANT 2^20 threads"?

Comment: I see no need for multi-dimensional addressing here.  You can get 1024 threads in a block, then divide your linear space into 2^10 linear blocks; the x dimension easily supports that.  Multi-dimensional indexing where we are just pairwise adding seems a bunch of extra (human) work for no benefit?

Comment: "However, the actual maximum number of threads per block and blocks per grid that can be used in a CUDA program is limited by the available resources on the GPU" This is wrong. The hardware available resources restrict how many threads can be **resident** on each SM and therefore on the whole GPU, which does have performance implications, but it doesn't restrict you programmatically. As long as one block doesn't take more resources than one full SM can deliver, you can still launch the kernel. For a normal launch the blocks/threads don't all have to be resident in parallel.

Comment: And multidimensional grids and blocks don't change anything about that resource usage/residency, so in terms of that your parameters will be equivalent to launching 16³ blocks of 512 threads in 1D blocks and grid. Depending on your usage of the 3D indices you might even decrease performance by launching many "boundary" blocks that have less or no work to do.

Comment: Leaving aside the pointlessness of using a 3D block, how did you decide that you need the *cube root* of  2048 blocks? That makes no sense. 2048 = 2^11 so any combination of three powers of 2 which sum to 11 will give the exact block count -- (16,16,8)  or (32,8,8) or (256,4,4), etc

Comment: @talonmies, I wanted to keep all the dimension values as much equal as possible.

Comment: Again why? All of your questions about block sizes you have posted over the last few months  have these completely artificial requirements which make no sense and you are doing nothing but confuse yourself and waste others time

Comment: @talonmies, *Again why?* --- No specific reason. I am just fond of symmetry.

Comment: @talonmies, *which make no sense and you are doing nothing but confuse yourself and waste others time* --- I am learning by experiment.

Answer (score 1):

> We need 2^20 = 10,48,576 threads.

You don’t, but let’s accept that premise for the moment.

> So, the declaration for threads per block would be:
>
> `dim3 threads_per_block(8, 8, 8); //512`

OK.

> So the declaration will look like as follows:
>
> `dim3 blocks_per_grid(16,16,16); //4096`
>
> Is this calculation correct?

No. 4096 * 512 = 2097152. You have twice as many threads as you state you need.

Comment: Plz, write something about my reasoning for qube-rooting; and plz write the correct calculation for the second case --- do you suggest 16x16x8 = 2048?